# Can I use present perfect instead of past simple in this sentence?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, past-simple

***There was a bus drivers' strike last week, so ....(there/be) no buses.***
I question if I can use **there has been** in this example. I thought we could use present perfect because we still do not see any buses, so I used present perfect. But when I checked it with the answer key, the answer was **there were**.
Can you help me, please?

Comment: **There was a strike last week** means that it has finished; otherwise we would say **there is a strike** or **the bus drivers have been on strike since last week**.

Comment: Who says we 'still do not see' any buses? There **was** a bus driver's strike last week, so there **were** no buses.